# How to send data from child to parent through a click event within the parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have a React app that builds quizzes. Within the parent component, `<CreateQuiz/>`, there is a child `<QuestionForm/>` component. Also within the `<CreateQuiz/>` component, there is a button, "Add Question," which adds another `<QuestionForm/>` component as a child.

I'm having trouble coming up with an elegant solution that checks if all input fields have been filled out before adding another `<QuestionForm/>` component when the "Add Question" button is clicked.

Here is my code for the `<CreateQuiz/>` component:

```
function CreateGame() {
  const [questionsArray, setQuestionsArray] = useState([
    { value: true, id: nanoid() },
  ]);

  const addQuestion = () =>
    setQuestionsArray((prevState) => [
      ...prevState,
      { value: true, id: nanoid() },
    ]);

  return (
    <div id="create-game">
      <h1>Quiz Creator</h1>
      <div className="container">
        {questionsArray.map((question) => (
          <QuestionForm
            key={question.id}
            id={question.id}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="buttons">
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            addQuestion();
          }}
        >
          Add Question
        </button>
        <button>Create Quiz</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `<QuestionForm/>` component just consists of a form with an `input` state for all the input values (question, answerOne, answerTwo, answerThree, answerFour, correctAnswer) along with an onChange handler function for the values.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can place a check mechanism inside addQuestion event handler which reduces the questionsArray state variable to see if value for all input is not undefined.

Comment: But the addQuestion event handler is in the parent component. Could you elaborate?

Comment: it is hard to follow your code because some information is missing. I am guessing you need to use Context API and possibly reducer functions.